# SQL error when starting project in VS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I am learning asp.net / C# at my job.  I was practicing using VS community edition.  Now I have installed 2017 professional edition and SQL Server 2012 (after removing CE version).  When I try to run a project in VS, I get this error message:  Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  Googling this error tells me that it is trying to access components from SQL CE 4.0.  How can I ensure that SQL CE is completely removed from my machine?  Are there any other ways to address this problem?

Comment: It sounds like you either need to get the dependency from nuget (right-click on the solution and select "restore nuget packages"), or the package you're using is incompatible with the project type (e.g. trying to use a .NET Core package in a .NET Framework project)

Comment: Remove this part in web.config..System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the reference of the 'System.Data.SqlServerCe' from your project as I understand that you don't need it anymore.
You can do this by right clicking in references of project and unchecked it  or by deleting from web.config

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the reference to SQL CE. By the text of the error message, the refence would be `System.Data.SqlServerCe`. Here's more on [how to add or remove references to a project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)
Hope it helps.